# Change "Subscription(s)" Verbiage on WooCommerce Subscriptions

Tags: woocommerce-subscriptions

I'd like to display another word like Membership(s) or similar instead of Subscription(s) on the customer facing displays for WooCommerce Subscriptions. I've seen some examples of replacing other text but not this one. Has anyone had experience with this?

I've reviewed similar questions online but have not found a suitable code example.